# Looking for a compressing algorithm that match this code

Tags: python, algorithm, compression

I am trying to write a tool to modify a game save. To do so, I need to decompress and compress the save. I found this decompressing algorithm for the save (that works), but I don't understand the code, so I don't know how to compress the data.

Does anyone find this familiar to any compression/decompression algorithms?

Thanks!

```
def get_bit(buffer, ref_pointer, ref_filter, length):
    result = 0
    current = buffer[ref_pointer.value]
    print(current)
    for i in range(length):
        result <<= 1
        if current & ref_filter.value:
            result |= 0x1
        ref_filter.value >>= 1
        if ref_filter.value == 0:
            ref_pointer.value += 1
            current = buffer[ref_pointer.value]
            ref_filter.value = 0x80
    return result

def decompress(buffer, decode, length):
    ref_pointer = Ref(0)
    ref_filter = Ref(0x80)
    dest = 0
    dic = [0] * 0x2010
    while ref_pointer.value < length:
        print(ref_pointer.value, ref_filter.value, dest)
        bits = get_bit(buffer, ref_pointer, ref_filter, 1)
        if ref_pointer.value >= length:
            return dest
        if bits:
            bits = get_bit(buffer, ref_pointer, ref_filter, 8)
            if ref_pointer.value >= length:
                print(dic)
                return dest
            decode[dest] = bits
            dic[dest & 0x1fff] = bits
            dest += 1
        else:
            bits = get_bit(buffer, ref_pointer, ref_filter, 13)
            if ref_pointer.value >= length:
                print(dic)
                return dest
            index = bits - 1
            bits = get_bit(buffer, ref_pointer, ref_filter, 4)
            if ref_pointer.value >= length:
                print(dic)
                return dest
            bits += 3
            for i in range(bits):
                dic[dest & 0x1fff] = dic[index + i]
                decode[dest] = dic[index + i]
                dest += 1
    print(dic)
    return dest
```

Comment: Can't you find the compression code at the same source? Why not just use a standard compression library instead of reverse-engineering something?

Comment: @Barmar Presumably because a standard compression library won't work for the game in question.

Comment: What is `Ref`??

Comment: Asking for code/algorithm identifications is beyond the [scope](/help/on-topic) of this site, as set out in the [help].